# get a list of primary keys after inserting multiple entries

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python module MySQLDb to insert multiple entries (sometimes up to 300) at once.  My sql looks something like...

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (row2,row3) values 
(row2_entry1,row3_entry1),(row2_entry2,row3_entry2),........(row2_entry300,row3_entry300)
```

The primary key for this table is auto incremented.  What I want is a list of primary keys of the entries entered into the table.  How do I do this with a batch

Comment: you can do a transaction, and get the id using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns just a single value. In case of batch insert, it will return the primary key value of the first inserted row.

You could use a GUID token to keep track of rows which are part of a batch insert operation. Add an extra `varchar(32)` column named `batch_insert_id` to your table. While doing batch insert, use a known GUID value. After insertion, execute a select query to get primary keys of the inserted rows.

```
import uuid

batch_insert_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
# Execute your batch insert query, with batch_insert_id 
# as value of batch_insert_id for all rows
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE batch_insert_id = '%s'", (batch_insert_id,))
primary_keys = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: A clever work around.  I'm not sure if I will be allowed to do this but I'll give you the correct answer since your solution would work.  Thanks for the help.